# jQuery prop counter with updated iterations

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, prop

I've used the jQuery [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)-method with the `counter`-property to create an animation that counts from 0 to the value from the `.count`-string through an `each`-loop.

This works as intended, but I would like to increase this value by 3, 2 and 1 respectively, set by the variables `cowsIncrement`, `sheepIncrement` and `pigsIncrement`. Each increment has to happen in 3, 2 and 1-second intervals as well (similiar to the increment value), and it has to run infinitely with the same animation. How would I go about doing this?

Can somebody provide solution from jQuery/Vanilla Js?

```js
// #count1
let cowsIncrement = 3;

// #count2
let sheepIncrement = 2;

// #count3
let pigsIncrement = 1;

$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('de-DE'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="count" id="count1">3000</div><span>cows</span>
<div class="count" id="count2">2000</div><span>sheep</span>
<div class="count" id="count3">1000</div><span>pigs</span>
```

Comment: I don't understand how you want to use the increments. jQuery calculates the increment automatically based on the duration and easing function.

Comment: I want e.g. the `cowsIncrement` variable to be added onto `#count1` after 3 seconds, so the amount is 3003. After another 3 seconds, it's added again, so the amount is 3006 etc. - the variables don't have to be used, I just put them there for demonstration. @Barmar

Comment: This is after it goes from 0 to 3000 in the first 1.5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, correct @Barmar

Comment: Use `complete:` to run a function when this animation completes. It can start a new animation that uses the increments. Put them in an object whose key is an attribute of the element being animated.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write an answer showing how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object that maps element IDs to the corresponding increments. Then use a `complete:` function that starts repeated animations with 3-second durations and the appropriate increment.

The key to getting the animations to repeat at the end is to use a named function, so it can call itself in the `complete:` option.

```js
// #count1
let cowsIncrement = 3;

// #count2
let sheepIncrement = 2;

// #count3
let pigsIncrement = 1;

const increments = {
  count1: cowsIncrement,
  count2: sheepIncrement,
  count3: pigsIncrement
};

$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('de-DE'));
    },
    complete: repeatAnimation
  });
});

function repeatAnimation() {
  let increment = increments[this.id];
  let current = Number($(this).prop('Counter'));
  console.log(this.id, current, increment);
  $(this).animate({
      Counter: current + increment
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString('de-DE'));
    },
    complete: repeatAnimation
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="count" id="count1">3000</div><span>cows</span>
<div class="count" id="count2">2000</div><span>sheep</span>
<div class="count" id="count3">1000</div><span>pigs</span>
```